# Server Showing Default CGI page on my VPS hosting

Tags: apache-2.2, php, vps, cgi

I am getting default cgi [http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi]page even after placing index.php in the root/public_html folder.

The Httpd Conf on my VPS have the following entry

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80 *>
    ServerName server1.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias cpanel.* whm.* webmail.* webdisk.* autodiscover.* autoconfig.*
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache/htdocs
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup nobody nobody
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    <IfModule core.c>
        SSLProxyEngine On
    </IfModule>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cpanel\.
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://127.0.0.1:2083/$1 [P]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^webmail\.
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://127.0.0.1:2096/$1 [P]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^whm\.
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://127.0.0.1:2087/$1 [P]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^webdisk\.
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://127.0.0.1:2078/$1 [P]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cpanel\.
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://127.0.0.1:2082/$1 [P]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^webmail\.
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://127.0.0.1:2095/$1 [P]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^whm\.
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://127.0.0.1:2086/$1 [P]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^webdisk\.
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://127.0.0.1:2077/$1 [P]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^autodiscover\.
    RewriteRule ^[^?]*(\?.*)? http://127.0.0.1/cgi-sys/autodiscover.cgi [P]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^autoconfig\.
    RewriteRule ^[^?]*(\?.*)? http://127.0.0.1/cgi-sys/autoconfig.cgi [P]
    UseCanonicalName Off
</VirtualHost>
```

What changes i need to make such that the dedicated IP loads the index.php from public_html folder.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your documentroot will need to change from
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache/htdocs

to

```
DocumentRoot /root/public_html
```

/root is an unusual place to have public html and if you have selinux running you will be blocked from accessing it there, check with `sestatus` if in doubt

If you still have no luck try a basic vhost like the below and then gradually change the entries for those from yours above until you spot your problem

```
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80>
    ServerName server1.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /root/public_html
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    <Directory /root/public_html>
     order allow, deny
     allow from all
    </Directory
</VirtualHost>
```